# Blender default UV Mapping

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, blender

Coming from 3d Studio, I am used to primitive and procedurally generated objects (ruled, lathed, extruded, NURB-based) having UV mapping coordinates by default, and in the case of more complex meshes, breaking out a more manual mapping process.

I am currently having difficulty in Blender, because is seems as though no items have default mappings and that unwrapping need to occur for every mesh as it is created.  Is this correct?

I plan on pulling everything into unity 3d for simple tests it seems excessive to do these steps.

Thanks

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know 3ds and I am not sure if I understand you right. What you can do in Blender is applying a texture to a model without UV mapping. And you can of course assign multiple materials to one object each one with a different texture and all without doing UV mapping. I just opened an old sample and tried it out - you can download it [here](http://files.scio.de/public/2MatsTextures.blend.zip).

But I found out that this not true if you want to import your Blender objects into Unity3D. From my experience there is no chance to get the objects's texture displayed in Unity3D if it has no explicit UV mapping. Furtheron I did not manage to get an object with two different textures straight into Unity3D. In that case I use parenting or a single texture, which I assume to be faster when rendering. I wrote a blog article about that, maybe it helps you: [Working with Blender 2.59 And Unity3D 3.4](http://www.scio.de/en/blog-a-neues/scio-development-blog/entry/working-with-blender-259-and-unity3d-34)

Answer (score 1):

Blender does give objects a default UV mapping; it's just that it pretty much equals "slap each face on the texture from `[0,0]` to `[1,1]`". So yeah if you want a "nicer" UV map you'll have to do something manually.